# How optimize these queries?

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

can I avoid INNER JOIN in these queries?

```
"SELECT posts.status, posts.reports, posts.post_id, 
        posts.reply_counts, posts.sender, posts.content, 
        posts.image, posts.thumb, posts.date, 
        members.username, members.avatar, members.state 
 FROM posts 
    INNER JOIN members ON posts.sender = members.member_id 
 WHERE posts.parent_id=0 
    AND posts.wall_id=0 
    AND (
          (members.status=".MEMBER_STATUS_ACTIVE." AND 
           posts.reports<".MAX_REPORT_HIDE." 
           AND posts.status=".POST_STATUS_ACTIVE."
          )
         OR 
         ".$bAdmin."=1 
         OR 
           (".$bMod."=1 AND 
             posts.status<>".POST_STATUS_DELETED."
           )
       ) 
    AND posts.private_id=0 
 ORDER BY posts.post_id DESC, posts.date DESC 
 LIMIT ".(($pagenum-1) * PAGINATION).",".PAGINATION.";"


"SELECT posts.status, posts.reports, posts.post_id, posts.reply_counts, 
        posts.sender, posts.content, posts.image, posts.thumb, posts.date, 
        members.username, members.avatar, members.state 
 FROM posts 
    INNER JOIN members ON posts.sender = members.member_id 
    INNER JOIN notifies ON posts.post_id=notifies.post_id 
 WHERE notifies.member_id=".$member_id." AND 
       posts.parent_id=0 AND 
       members.status=".MEMBER_STATUS_ACTIVE." AND 
       posts.reports<".MAX_REPORT_HIDE." AND 
       posts.status=".POST_STATUS_ACTIVE." AND 
       posts.private_id=0 
 ORDER BY posts.last_update DESC, posts.date DESC 
 LIMIT ".(($pagenum-1) * PAGINATION).",".PAGINATION.";"
```

Comment: The question is 'why would you want to?'

Comment: It's up to you. If you need `members` fields then join it's table. Also I think you should move `members.status = ".MEMBER_STATUS_ACTIVE."` to the `ON` clause of the `INNER JOIN members`

Comment: @Strawberry because of performance.

Comment: @SAMPro can I move it there? not sure how.

Comment: If performance is an issue, look first at your indexes and the result of EXPLAIN SELECT...

Comment: `Where` clause is applied to the result set but `ON` clause is specify how to join tables. When you join two tables, each row from table 1 will multiplied to table 2, so if you move the condition to the `ON` clause you will decrease that multiplicity before creating result set .

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you need all rows from both table once match exist then you should use inner join.

Comment: It would be more corect to say that if you want to RETRIEVE data from both tables AND/OR FILTER using data from each table then you MUST use a join.

Comment: @symcbean Yes exactly what i mean.